# Guitar Drummer Pa system

Tags: guitar, drums, speakers, garage-band

So me and a friend have got a partial band lol.  Its me on guitar and vocals and him on the drums.  My question is how should we set up.  we usually play in my shop metal walls and concrete floors.  I just recently purchased a peavey 4 channel mixer and 2 Yamaha speakers.  We have played like 3 times with it and honestly for us not having any idea about how to place anything it doesnt sound to bad.  I just think it could be better.  Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Like our speaker placement? Usually we just kinda throw it up and play.....but should both speakers be way away from us? Is it ok that I sit beside the drummer or is this all just a personal preference?

Comment: What does it sound like to other people?  Are you planning on playing in other venues or just in the shop?

Comment: Well they say it sounds good.  For now no we will stick to the shop we are guna have to get a little better before we try playing for more people than family.

Answer (score 1):

You must have seen plenty of bands in gig situations, so know how that set up works.

But for rehearsals, it doesn't have to be like that - in fact, it's often detrimental, in the early stages, if it is.

First off, in rehearsals, eye contact is essential, as is being able to hear yourself, and everyone else, clearly.

Drums don't sound so good when played in corners, so put them half-way along a flat wall. P.a. speakers can be far from each other, close to opposite walls, but unlike a gig situation, where they're for the audience, you can angle them round, so they're facing you - whether it's the two, or a bigger band with bass, keys, another guitar, etc. If they feed back, they could be swung away from being directly in line with mics. Or, you could do a rare thing - turn the volume down. Several auditions I've been to (which is a rehearsal set up, or should be), everything's been so loud, I couldn't listen to things clearly. Waste of time!

So, your amp. for now, middle of room, facing drummer, you between it and drummer. Speakers on stands (or chairs/tables for now). But really experimentation is the name of the game - try out different placings, but maybe use this template as a start point. Good luck!

Comment: Turning down the volume is an excellent idea - everything to reduce volume and noise will improve your sound and keep your ears happy and healthy. "Metal walls and concrete floors" may be problematic - try placing some old carpets on the floors and walls if you have too much noise going on.